# Always Show 4 Decimal Places

Tags: xlwt, decimal

Is it possible to force a cell to always show 4 decimal places using xlwt? Regardless of the number actually present after the decimal place. I have done some searching and I can find a string to always reduce to 2 decimal places, but I need certain cells on my sheet to show 4.

Answer (score 4):

Use xlwt styles. Here's a simple example:

```
import xlwt


book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet("test")

decimal_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
decimal_style.num_format_str = '0.0000'

sheet.write(0, 0, 1.23456789, decimal_style)
sheet.write(0, 1, 1.01, decimal_style)

book.save('test.xls')
```

Or you can use `xlwt.easyxf` for defining styles. Hope that helps.